# how to use retrace.bat in android

Tags: android, proguard

I am using **retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt** at the command prompt.

But it's showing **nothing** in obfuscated_trace.txt. 
mapping.txt copy from project.

**step:**

1. `cd  *\android-sdk\tools\proguard\bin`
2. `retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt`

Answer (score 15):

You can have Retrace GUI instead. Look [here](http://blog.simplyadvanced.net/android-how-to-decode-proguards-obfuscated-code-from-stack-trace/) for step by step details on how to use Retrace GUI.

Basic steps follow:

1. Open /tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.bat
2. Select the “ReTrace” option on the left column.
3. Add your mapping file and obfuscated stack trace.
4. Click “ReTrace!”

Comment: Where is the download button the link that you have mentioned?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal What download button? You dont need to download anything just open /tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.bat The link was just a step by step guidance as I already summarized it to 4 steps above.

Comment: Sorry, your first sentence is misleading actually: "You can have Retrace GUI look here It is easier.", although i followed the link to get my task done. If you can modify the answer then that will be great for someone like me. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find any other Retrace that the menu on left panel... is that the one I need to click after pointing the mapping file and pasting the obfuscated stacktrace in GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the below points.

1. open the terminal/cmd
2. cd **/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.jar
3. refer the attached image, retrace GUI pop's up
4. select your mapping file and copy-paste your obfuscated stacktrace

That's it. Simple and easy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your obfuscated_trace.xt has to actually have a stack trace in it .... paste a stack trace inside of this file and run it again and to unobfuscate the code

Comment: "obfuscated_trace.xt has to actually have a stack trace in it" ,it's right,thanks